# Backbone.js collection initialization query

Tags: backbone.js

I am learing backbone.js and came across interesting scenario.

```
var EmployeeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http://localhost:80/employee/employee/employeelist'
});

alert('Collection created');

var employeeList = new EmployeeList();
employeeList.on("reset", function(){
  alert(employeeList.length + " item(s) found");
});
employeeList.fetch();

alert(employeeList.length);
```

I am not able to understand why the second alert doesn't show length properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert `alert(employeeList.length + " item(s) found")` should display the correct length, because it is run after the `reset` -event is triggered following the populating of the collection.

The alert `alert(employeeList.length);` right after `fetch` shouldn't give you consistently the correct result, because collections are fetched `asynchronously` by default, so the alert is processed right after the AJAX-call for the `fetch` has been fired and hasn't possibly returned yet.

Timeline is something like this

1. Fetch triggers ajax call to `'http://localhost:80/employee/employee/employeelist'`
2. `alert(employeeList.length);` is called, but collection is empty
3. Fetch returns eventually triggering a `reset`
4. `alert(employeeList.length + " item(s) found");` is called

Comment: When you say fetched "asynchronously", does that mean its because of the delay I am not seeing the result.

Comment: asynchronous means that the program doesn't wait for the query to return, but instead goes straight to the next line. when the query is completed it will then react with the `reset` -event

Comment: But when I am running this in my local. I am seeing item 4 alert first and item 2 alert later. So, should I not be getting the correct result even then? Should I always put this kind of code in events?

Comment: Yeah, if you need to do something with a collection/model after a fetch or other CRUD-operation, ALWAYS do it after the appropriate event has been fired and do it by listening to that event.